# PySimpleGUI - Is it possible to update Cavas size?

Tags: canvas, pysimplegui

I have a GUI with a canvas where I plot a user selection of variables.

The more variables selected the smaller the graphs for each variable get squeeze on the fixed canvas size.

```py
    
    [sg.Column(layout=[
    [sg.Canvas(key='fig_p6',size=(15.2*hx , vsize*hy))]
    ]
```

Question: Is it possible to resize the sg.Canvas size by updating it?

```py
    vsize=no_of_selected_variables*3
    window['fig_p6'].update(size=((15.2), (vsize)))
```

Looking forward for your feedback.

Kind Regards,

Vic Q

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out.

Instead of reloading the whole windown as shown in multiple blogs out there, the solution is much simple:

1. To calculate the new size
2. to update the size of the column where the canvas is located:

```py
    c_size=(15.2*hx , vsize*hy)
    window['-var_col_fig_p6-'].set_size(c_size)
```

3. To update the size of the canvas itsel

```py
    window['fig_p6'].set_size(c_size)
```